# IllegalStateException while search from Edittext

Tags: android, listview, filter, illegalstateexception

I am using `TextWatcher` to filter result of my listview. But i'm getting below error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.  with Adapter`

I haven't used background thread anywhere. How to get away from this ???

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected  void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                contactNameList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                //Log.e("RESULT:",results.values.toString() );
                //                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                //                        public void run() {
                try {
                    if (results.count > 0) {
                        mContactListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        mContactListAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }  

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected synchronized FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                ArrayList<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

                // set the Filtered result to return
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM "
                            +MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_CONTACT
                            +" WHERE "
                            +MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CNT_NICK_NAME
                            +" LIKE '"+constraint.toString()+"%'"
                            +" ORDER BY "
                            +(prefs.getOrderBy().equalsIgnoreCase("")? MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CNT_NICK_NAME: prefs.getOrderBy()) 
                            +" COLLATE NOCASE;";                                      

                    Log.e("FILTER SQL ",sql);
                    synchronized (this) {
                        fetchContactData(sql);            
                    }


                    results.count = contactNameList.size();
                    results.values = contactNameList;
                    return results;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;                
            }
        };
        return filter;            
    }
```

**EDIT -Whole logcat:**

`E/onQueryTextChange(17748): contact onTextChanged:p
08-22 19:18:10.035: E/FILTER SQL(17748): SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE cnt_nick LIKE 'p%' ORDER BY cnt_nick COLLATE NOCASE;
08-22 19:18:10.047: D/AndroidRuntime(17748): Shutting down VM
08-22 19:18:10.048: W/dalvikvm(17748): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418aa9a8)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131492994, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.ecosmob.contactpro.contacts.ContactFragment$ContactListAdapter)]
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1559)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2052)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1589)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
      08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:690)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14118)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4467)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1947)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4893)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    08-22 19:18:10.060: E/AndroidRuntime(17748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

**EDIT - 2 (SearchBox Edittext):**

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Log.e("onQueryTextChange","contact beforeTextChanged:"+ s);    
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Log.e("onQueryTextChange","contact afterTextChanged:"+ s);
            try{
                searchText = s.toString();
                if(searchText.length() > 0){
                    mContactListAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchText);    

                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("onQueryTextChange","contact onTextChanged:"+ s);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace please?

Comment: Thanks for the stacktrace. Are you certain that you have not called getFilter from a background Thread?

Comment: Can you post the code where you use your adapter?

Comment: @hoomi: check the edits.

Comment: @I-droid did you try my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought problem would be that while adding quick characters in `searchBox`; it would be fetching contacts in array too quickly. mean while `notifyDatasetChanged()` doesn't get enough time to get called. So, I ended with following solution:

```
 searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        private final int TRIGGER_SERACH = 1;
        private final long SEARCH_TRIGGER_DELAY_IN_MS = 300;  

        private Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == TRIGGER_SERACH) {  
                    try{
                        //if(searchText.length() > 0){  
                            mContactListAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchText);                             
                        //}
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }  
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Log.e("onQueryTextChange","contact beforeTextChanged:"+ s);   
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Log.e("onQueryTextChange","contact afterTextChanged:"+ s);
            searchText = s.toString();
            handler.removeMessages(TRIGGER_SERACH);
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(TRIGGER_SERACH, SEARCH_TRIGGER_DELAY_IN_MS);
            Log.e("onQueryTextChange","contact onTextChanged:"+ s);        
        }
    });
```

This will wait for user to finish entering words, then only start search.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of your code does not make sense to me. in `performFiltering` method you have the following lines:

```
results.count = contactNameList.size(); 
results.values = contactNameList;
```

and then in `publishResults` you have the following line:

```
contactNameList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
```

The only place that I think you are updating the `contactNameList` is in `fetchContactData` method. This method is being called in the background thread. And I believe you are using `contactNameList` in your adapter. as well. That is why you are getting this error. Try the following instead:

```
private ArrayList<String> fetchContactData(String query) {
    //Do your query here but DO NOT update contactNameList
    return <the arrayList>
}
```

Then in your `performFiltering` replace the following lines:

```
synchronized (this) {
       fetchContactData(sql);            
}

results.count = contactNameList.size(); 
results.values = contactNameList;
```

with this:

```
ArrayList<String> temp;
synchronized (this) {
       temp = fetchContactData(sql);            
}

results.count = temp.size(); 
results.values = temp;
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Yes I just tried your code today, but problem was still there.